# Why my gas stove delays in turning on?

Tags: stove

When I turn on my gas stove, the ignitor clicks and it takes a good 15 seconds and it explodes on.  What does it mean?

Comment: Probably the ignitors of all rings fire at the same time but the one on your main ring has failed, it isn't until gas reaches as far as an adjacent ignitor that it ignites. I'd see if the ignitor can be replaced, this is potentially dangerous.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that a few of the gas nozzles closest to the ignitor are clogged or blocked, and so the burner will not light until there is so much gas pumped out that it eventually makes it to the igniter, and hence the explosion. You should clean it out, and if that doesn't work, replace the ignitor.